# subscribe().add() method called with parameter which is not of type Subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am new to Angular (just learning) and I am trying to understand the following code. In this code (I simplified it from another app I have seen on Github) `subscribe` method calls `add` method with the parameter `resolve` (from Promise) - so I have a few questions:

1. Doesn't parameter passed to add mehtod have to be of type `Subscription' ?
2. What does framework do with passed `resolve` parameter. I Thought the parameter must be of type Subscription and framework calls `<Subscription>.unsubscribe()` on it.

```
const numbers: Observable<number> = interval(5000);
  const takeFourNumbers = numbers.pipe(take(4));
  const promise$ = new Promise<void>(resolve => {
    // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
    takeFourNumbers.subscribe()
      .add(resolve);
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log("My result is ", result);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit of an odd piece of code.

Every `Subscription` has an `.add(` function, which is used to trigger something else on teardown, this is when that subscription ends (either because the stream errors, completes, or you call .unsubscribe())

The parameter that `.add(` takes can be a function (in which case it just gets called on teardown), or another subscription, in which case it will call `.unsubscribe()` to it.

It's not really used too much unless you're building something low-level (such a library)

In this case, `takeFourNumbers` is a stream that will emit 4 numbers in succession, 1 second between each emission and then complete. `promise$` is a Promise that when `takeForNumbers` ends after 4 seconds it will resolve with `void`, because the teardown will call the function passed to `.add(`, which is resolve, and it doesn't give any parameter as far as I know.

Then on that promise it calls `.then(` to log the result when that happens, but I expect the result to be `undefined`.